# How to customize Carousel in Bootstrap theme?

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal and want to know how I can customize a certain feature on the site.

I am using the [Drupal Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and I have added the Bootstrap Carousel in `\sites\all\themes\bootstrap\theme\system\page.tpl.php`

The thing is I have hard coded the images for the carousel like so:

```
<div class="item">
      <img src="<?php print $base_url . '\sites\all\themes\bootstrap\screenshot.png'; ?>" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I want is to set it up so that the user can choose the images for the Carousel from the user interface under Appearance > Theme Settings.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you make title more meaningful? I bet at least half questions here are about what can be called Drupal customisation.

Comment: @Mołot True, have updated now

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not the right way to use such theme, you should not touch drupal core or any contribute module or theme.
For example in bootstrap theme you create sub theme that based om bootstrap theme, if you read the documentation of bootstrap theme you will find the instruction how to do that.
For the second part, you may need to create a content type first, add image field and then use views module to display your slide show, you can find a module called views bootstrap to make the used of bootstrap elements.

Drupal is powerful CMS but its not easy one.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is that don't play with core files. Just disable **Carousel** in theme and add your own one. For this purpose;

1. Create a **Content Type** (including images or other fields if you want).
2. Install [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).
3. Create a **Views**(Block type) and select a format as **slideshow**.
4. Go to **admin/structure/block** and place your recently created **slideshow** block in desired region.